# ¿Cómo puedo generar un checkbox y un textbox dinámicamente para cada miniatura?

Tags: c#

Tengo un método que agrega imágenes y las va colocando sucesivamente (tantas imágenes hayan en la carpeta) dentro de `flowLayoutPanelMain.Controls.Add(imageViewer)`. He logrado colocar un checkbox y un textbox arriba de cada imagen, pero estos dos objetos sólo aparecen a la par con cada imagen si los creo usando `CheckBox cboxToSave = new CheckBox()` y `TextBox txFileName = new TextBox()` dentro del método. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cada thumbnail tenga su propio `checkbox` y `textbox`? El problema es que el `cboxToSave` y el `txFileName` son necesarios para ser utilizados más adelante por otras funciones, por esa razón no deben ser declarados dentro de `public void AddImage(string imageFilename)`. ¿Alguna idea?

(El código de la manera que aparece abajo sólo creará un `checkbox` y un `textbox` para la última imagen.)

```
 public void AddImage(string imageFilename)
        {
            //TextBox txFileName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            //CheckBox cboxToSave = new CheckBox();
            //TextBox txFileName = new TextBox();
            try
            {
                // thread safe
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(m_AddImageDelegate, imageFilename);
                }
                else
                {
                    int size = ImageSize;
                    lbNumberOfFiles.Visible = true;
                    lbHowMany.Visible = true;
                    //CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();

                    ImageViewer imageViewer = new ImageViewer();
                    //ImageViewer selectedFile = new ImageViewer();
                    //selectedFile.cboxToSave.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.ReceiveCheckedChanged);
                    imageViewer.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
                    imageViewer.LoadImage(imageFilename, 256, 256);
                    imageViewer.Width = size;
                    imageViewer.Height = size;
                    imageViewer.IsThumbnail = true;

                    imageViewer.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(imageViewer_MouseClick);

                    txFileName.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
                    txFileName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                    txFileName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 5);
                    txFileName.Name = "txFileName";
                    txFileName.ReadOnly = true;
                    txFileName.BackColor = Color.Empty;
                    txFileName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 14);
                    txFileName.BringToFront();

                    cboxToSave.AutoSize = true;
                    cboxToSave.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 4);
                    cboxToSave.Name = "cboxToSave";
                    cboxToSave.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 14);
                    cboxToSave.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                    //cboxToSave.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cboxToSave_CheckedChanged);

                    //txFileName.TabIndex = 1;
                    //txFileName.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.txFileName_Leave);
                    //txFileName.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.txFileName_MouseHover);

                    txInformation.Text = imageFilename;
                    SetProgressBar();
                    counter++;
                    lbHowMany.Text = "Images";
                    lbNumberOfFiles.Text = counter.ToString();
                    txFileName.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageFilename);
                    this.OnImageSizeChanged += new ThumbnailImageEventHandler(imageViewer.ImageSizeChanged);
                    //passes the pictures to the main picture container 
                    this.flowLayoutPanelMain.Controls.Add(imageViewer);
                    imageViewer.Controls.Add(txFileName);
                    imageViewer.Controls.Add(cboxToSave);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error has ocurred. Error: " + e, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Yo crearía un control de usuario con los tres elementos y sería lo que añadiría al `flowlayoutpanel`.

Answer (score 1):

Bien voy a responder como dios manda que lo de antes era un comentario mas que una respuesta.

En tu caso yo me crearía un `UserControl` por ejemplo algo así:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public PictureBox image;
    public CheckBox checkBox1;
    public TextBox txFileName;
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

De esta forma añadiría a mi `flowLayoutPanelMain` de esta forma:

```
MyUserControl userControl = new MyUserControl();
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(userControl);
```

Esto te permitiría acceder a cada imagen, checkBox y al TextBox de cada uno de los objetos por separado y tener acceso a ellos sin ningún tipo de problema.

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Creo que comprendí. Ahora, si implemento un UserControl, digamos que un checkbox + textBox, ¿podré acceder a ellos de manera individual? Es decir, ¿podré identificar cuándo cada checkbox es ejecutado y cuándo cada textbox tiene texto? Porque cada textbox llevará el nombre del archivo, y cada checked checkbox indicará qué archivo fue seleccionado. Espero que tenga sentido lo que digo.

Comment: Al fin y al cabo son objetos a los que puedes acceder sin ningún tipo de problema, ya sea a su valor como apuntarte a sus eventos, etc. De todas formas además del textbox y el checkbox yo metería la imagen también en el UserControl y así tienes todos relacionados entre sí con el objeto creado

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver de la siguiente manera, sin necesidad de utilizar `UserControl`.

Este es el código modificado:

```
  public void AddImage(string imageFilename)
    {
        CheckBox cboxToSave = new CheckBox();
        TextBox txFileName = new TextBox();
        try
        {
            // thread safe
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(m_AddImageDelegate, imageFilename);
            }
            else
            {

                int size = ImageSize;
                lbNumberOfFiles.Visible = true;
                lbHowMany.Visible = true;
                ImageViewer imageViewer = new ImageViewer();

                imageViewer.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
                imageViewer.LoadImage(imageFilename, 256, 256);
                imageViewer.Width = size;
                imageViewer.Height = size;
                imageViewer.IsThumbnail = true;

                imageViewer.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(imageViewer_MouseClick);

                txFileName.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
                txFileName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                txFileName.Font = new Font(txFileName.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                txFileName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 3);
                txFileName.ReadOnly = true;
                txFileName.BackColor = Color.Empty;
                txFileName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 14);
                txFileName.BringToFront();

                cboxToSave.AutoSize = true;
                cboxToSave.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 4);
                cboxToSave.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 14);
                cboxToSave.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

                cboxToSave.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this._cboxToSave_CheckedChanged);

                txListErrors.Text = _txFileName.Text;

                counter++;
                txFileName.Name = "txFileName_" + counter;
                cboxToSave.Name = "cboxToSave_" + counter;
                imageViewer.Name = "imageViewer_" + counter;
                cboxToSave.AccessibleName = imageFilename; //-->Gets the filename to be used later.
                string getCkname = cboxToSave.Name.ToString();
                txInformation.Text = imageFilename;
                SetProgressBar();
                lbHowMany.Text = "Images";
                lbNumberOfFiles.Text = counter.ToString();
                txFileName.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imageFilename);

                _imageViewer = imageViewer;
                _cboxToSave = cboxToSave;
                _txFileName = txFileName;

                this.OnImageSizeChanged += new ThumbnailImageEventHandler(imageViewer.ImageSizeChanged);
                //passes the pictures to the main picture container 
                ThumbnailFlowLayoutPanel.Refresh();
                this.ThumbnailFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(imageViewer);
                imageViewer.Controls.Add(txFileName);
                imageViewer.Controls.Add(cboxToSave);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has ocurred. Error: " + e, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

Tuve que crear dos objetos al inicio del programa:

```
CheckBox _cboxToSave = new CheckBox();
TextBox _txFileName = new TextBox();
```

Y heredar de los dos otros objetos dinámicos `CheckBox cboxToSave = new CheckBox();`
y `TextBox txFileName = new TextBox();` cada uno de sus atributos. De esa manera, `_cboxToSave = cboxToSave`  y `_txFileName = txFileName` por ser públicos, pueden ser accedidos en cualquier área. También agregué un solo `Event Args` para todos los `checkboxes`.

```
    private void _cboxToSave_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //_cboxToSave takes the individual attributes of every cboxToSave generated dyncamically
        _cboxToSave = sender as CheckBox; //--->necessary event handler
        RemoveOrSendSelectedFiles();
    }
```

Pude agregar un método `SelectAll()` y `RemoveSelectedItems()`. Utilicé el atributo `AccessibleName` (`_cboxToSave.AccessibleName`) para almacenar el nombre de cada archivo cargado, es decir, cada checkbox dinámico tiene su propio `AccessibleName` y de esa manera pasarlo al query de SQL para guardar la imagen. El método `RemoveSelectedItems()` es similar a `SelectAll()`.

```
 private void SelectAll()
    {
        //this indicates if the ThumbnailFlowLayoutPanel is empty or has at least one image_viewer
        numLay = ThumbnailFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count;

        try
        {
            //less than 1 is 'empty'
            if (numLay < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please load a folder with images.", "Message");
            }
            else
                //there is at least an 'image_viewer'
                if (numLay >= 1)
            {
                ResetCheckboxes();
                int lbValue = Convert.ToInt32(lbNumberOfFiles.Text);

                //_imageViewer is used as object to find components in it and passes its individual attributes to image_viewer for every count
                for (int count = 1; count <= counter; count++)
                {
                    foreach (Control image_viewer in ThumbnailFlowLayoutPanel.Controls)
                    {
                        //it will be passing value of "imageViewer_" + 5
                        if (image_viewer.Name == "imageViewer_" + count)
                        {
                            //MessageBox.Show("FOUND!");

                            foreach (Control control in image_viewer.Controls)
                            {
                                //if (control.Name == "cboxToSave_" + 5)
                                CheckBox ckb = control as CheckBox;

                                if (control is CheckBox && control.Name == "cboxToSave_" + count)
                                {
                                    if (!ckb.Checked)
                                    {
                                        //MessageBox.Show("Check box is checked");
                                        ckb.Checked = true;
                                    }
                                }//end of second if
                            }//end of second foreach
                        }//end of first if
                    }//end of first foreach
                }//end of for loop
            }//end of if
        }//end of method
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error has ocurred. Error: " + ex, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```